# In liferay portlet preferences I am getting unsupportedoperationexception

Tags: liferay-6

I am getting unsupportedoperationexception in liferay 6.2 while using portletpreferences.
I am getting preferences from here

```
  PortletPreferences prefs = request.getPreferences();
```

Then setting the value in preferences

```
  prefs.setValue("test", "test"); 
  prefs.store();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get portletPreferences using code below:

```
   String portletResource = ParamUtil.getString(
                actionRequest, "portletResource");

   PortletPreferences portletPreferences = PortletPreferencesFactoryUtil.getPortletSetup(
                    actionRequest, portletResource);
```

Comment: portletresource is portletid